# web api in MVC no longer working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am using VS 2017 community.  I have been building web api s for years.  But something must have changed as I cannot get the simplest example to work.

I have a simple controller in the controller folder

```
public class TestApi : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

I have the necessary code in application start:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

But when I try and test the web api with a get like:

```
http://localhost:54014/api/testapi
```

I always get an xml message

```
Error
Message
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 
'http://localhost:54014/api/testapi'.
/Message
MessageDetail
No type was found that matches the controller named 'testapi'.
/MessageDetail
/Error
```

Here is the WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I am a couple of hours into head scratching on this. As I say I have built many MS web api implementations and this one has me baffled.

Comment: Try renaming your controller to TestApiController.

Comment: Thanks ... Tried that and still get the same error only with the controller named changed.

Comment: @patcapozzi show *WebApiConfig.cs*.

Comment: Added WebApiConfig.cs to question

Comment: I think it should work if you use name `TestApiController`. Try creating new web api with name `ProductController` and check if it is working or not.

Answer (score 3):

You should add   `Controller` suffix to your class name.

```
public class TestApiController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

When the app starts, the asp.net mvc frameworks looks for classes (which are inherited from `ApiController` or `Controller`) with this suffix and register them when building the route table. When a request comes to your app, the framework again look into the route table and direct the request to the corresponding controller and action method.

Make this change, rebuild your project and try again.

Comment: Ah yes the 'controller naming convention'  I do remember it now.  Thanks also to Scott Hannen

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the already provided answer (which is correct by the way) you can also consider using attribute routing over convention-based routing, where in this case it would not matter what the name of the controller is.

You already have it enabled Based on the *WebApiConfig.cs* and

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

So now it is just a matter of putting the attributes where needed

```
[RoutePrefix("api/testapi")]
public class TestApi : ApiController {

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")] //Matches GET api/testapi
    public IEnumerable<string> Get() {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Reference: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: I totally agree.  WebApi is problematic without Attribute based routing.